# Should a definite article be used when referring to a line of an algorithm

Tags: articles, definite-articles, science

In scientific articles an article is usually omitted when referring to figures, tables, etc. and a capital letter is used. For example I would state: "The data are shown in Figure 1."

I have an algorithm in my article and its lines are numbered. I want to refer to a certain line of the algorithm and I don't know whether the above also applies in this situation. Which of the following should I use:

- "on the line x",
- "on line x",
- "on Line x",

where "x" is a line number?

EDIT: An example of an algorithm:

```
Algorithm IsOne(i):
1: if i = 1
2:    return true
3: else
4:    return false
5: end if
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since it is a line of an algorithm "on line x" is more appropriate.

Comment: Also note that generally "line" and "page" start with lower case while "Chapter" and other logical divisions use upper case (in most style guides -- I believe the one major guide to disagree and use lower case for "chapter x" is Chicago). This is implied but not staff in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the constant on Line 1.  **correct**
Change the constant on the Line 1.  **incorrect**
Change the constant on the line with the *if*.  **correct**